# =IF(Q3="0-32",3.5x9.125,IF(Q3="33-93",8.5x11,IF(Q3="94-187",11x17)))

Tags: google-sheets-formula

What is wrong with my formula? Getting #ERROR! message. The 3.5x9.125 and so on is a paper size, and 0-32 and so on is print area per sq/in. I am trying to make Q4 determine the paper size based on the Q3 option selected from a pull down list.

Comment: Putting the formula in the title caught me off guard, but it would crack me up if one of the SO scrapper sites pulled that in and died.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the assignment this should help. `=IF(or(B48<32,B48=32),"3.5x9.125",IF(or(B48=93,B48=33,and(B48>33,B48<93)),"8.5x11",IF(or(B48=94,B48=187,and(B48>94,B48<187)),"11x17")))`